# Generate Complex Pyspark table involving Array, Pivot

Tags: arrays, pyspark, pivot

I have a table in the following format

```
+-------+--------+
|Column1|Column2 |
+-------+--------+
|[A, 1] |X       |
|[A, 1] |Y       |
|[B, 2] |Y       |
|[B, 2] |Z       |
|[C, 1] |X       |
|[C, 1] |Z       |
+-------+--------+
```

I need a table with the following result:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |[A, 1] |[B, 2] |[C, 1] |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|[A, 1] |[X, Y] |[Y]    |[X]    |
|[B, 2] |[Y]    |[Y, Z] |[Z]    |
|[C, 1] |[X]    |[Z]    |[X, Z] |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Or even better will be a result like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |[A, 1] |[B, 2] |[C, 1] |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|[A, 1] |2      |1      |1      |
|[B, 2] |1      |2      |1      |
|[C, 1] |1      |1      |2      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you need with words. Like this it may be misinterpreted.

Comment: I am looking for a correlation matrix which tells the number of values of Column2 that is present in two Column1 values.
Meaning, [A, 1] & [B, 2] have 1 common Column2 value. I want to tabulate all the values similar to 1 in the above case. Also note that Column 1 in my actual dataframe is a array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be expensive, especially for large data, but you can do `join` + `pivot`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import count

df.alias("l").join(df.alias("r"), on="Column2")\
    .select("l.Column1", "r.Column1")\
    .groupBy("l.Column1")\
    .pivot("r.Column1")\
    .agg(count("r.Column1"))\
    .show()
#+-------+------+------+------+
#|Column1|[A, 1]|[B, 2]|[C, 1]|
#+-------+------+------+------+
#| [A, 1]|     2|     1|     1|
#| [B, 2]|     1|     2|     1|
#| [C, 1]|     1|     1|     2|
#+-------+------+------+------+
```